# Enable Cors in Web Api Core 1.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cors, cross-domain

I need to enable Cross Origins Resource Sharing in my Web Api .Net Core, but nothing happens, I never have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the request header.

Here is Startup.cs config :

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {           

        services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                                                .AllowAnyMethod()
                                                                 .AllowAnyHeader()));
        services.AddMvc();            

        services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
        });
    }



 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        app.UseCors("AllowAll");
        ConfigureAuth(app);             
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Here is the response Header 
[Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XW92.png)

Comment: Is that the whole code? No  exception middleware or error pages? These can clear the cors headers, when an exception happens

Comment: No exception on middleware or in pages. I really don't know why it won't work. No error, in debug the code is executed, but no way to have the header

Comment: But are you getting any errors when calling your API?

Answer (score 0):

> You can configure CORS in Startup class  in the ConfigureServices method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
.         {
.             services.AddCors(options =>
.             {
.                 options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
.                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
.                .AllowAnyMethod()
.                .AllowAnyHeader()
.                .AllowCredentials());
.             });
.         }
```

> apply it to every request

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
}
```

> you can apply on Controller or Method Also e.g add attribute

```
 [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
```

`